# Error in node packages and node-sass

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, frontend, yarnpkg

I'm receiving this error in javascript console.
I already remove the node_modules and reinstall it and I already run npm rebuild node-sass.
I really don't know what to do anymore.
I'll be very grateful for your help.

```
app.js:20147 Uncaught Error: Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module 

build failed: Error: Missing binding /home/vagrant/Quality1/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57/binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 8.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Windows 32-bit with Node.js 6.x
  - Windows 64-bit with Node.js 6.x

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass --force` to build the binding for your current environment.
    at module.exports (/home/vagrant/Quality1/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:15:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/Quality1/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/Quality1/node_modules/sass-loader/index.js:4:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
```

**npm rebuild node-sass --force (response)**

`make: Leaving directory`/home/vagrant/Quality1/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp info ok 
Installed to /home/vagrant/Quality1/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57/binding.node

> node-sass@3.13.1 install /home/vagrant/Quality1/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
>   node scripts/install.js

node-sass build Binary found at /home/vagrant/Quality1/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57/binding.node

> node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall /home/vagrant/Quality1/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
>   node scripts/build.js

Binary found at /home/vagrant/Quality1/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57/binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine
node-sass@4.5.3 /home/vagrant/Quality1/node_modules/node-sass
node-sass@3.13.1 /home/vagrant/Quality1/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
`

Comment: Have you tried running `npm rebuild node-sass --force`

Comment: yes, I just did that. and no good result. It's still the same.

Comment: I also run npm cache clean. For see if it isnt some problem with cache, but it's still the same.

Comment: Could you post the output of `npm rebuild node-sass --force`

Comment: ok it seems to run ok.

Comment: make: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/Quality1/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp info ok 
Installed to /home/vagrant/Quality1/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57/binding.node

> node-sass@3.13.1 install /home/vagrant/Quality1/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

node-sass build Binary found at /home/vagrant/Quality1/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57/binding.node

Comment: > node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall /home/vagrant/Quality1/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Binary found at /home/vagrant/Quality1/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57/binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine
node-sass@4.5.3 /home/vagrant/Quality1/node_modules/node-sass
node-sass@3.13.1 /home/vagrant/Quality1/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass

Comment: it seems has compiled sass well

Comment: What was it that caused it to work?

Comment: I work in my job with a ubuntu and im my home with a win10. I updated npm in my home so when I went to the job in the next day I realize that error.

Comment: You should install ubuntu on your home computer

Comment: yes, I'll do that now. so unfortunately now I have to solve that problem

Answer (score 2):

change "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2"
to
"gulp-sass": "3.0.0" in package.json

clear the node_modules folder by removing it and then run

> **npm install**

again and it'll not give the error!

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I was wondering which dependency I need to upgrade to get rid of that non-supported node-sass version.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `node-sass@3.13.1`. There was never support for Node 8 for that version.

You can solve this problem in two ways:

1. Use `node-sass@4.5.3` or higher (currently the latest one is 4.7.2). Sometimes `node-sass` is the dependency of another package, then try to update this package.
2. Use Node 6. The easiest way to manage different versions of Node between your projects is to use [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) or [NVM Windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows). I also suggest you use [.nvmrc](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#nvmrc) file, that contains desired Node version. Then you will be able to switch between Node version with simply `$ nvm use` in a project directory.